# The location of plist file with defaults

Tags: plist, defaults

How to know the location of plist that `defaults read` reads. For example, `defaults read com.google.Keystone.Agent` returns the information.

```
{
    ActivesInfo =     {
        "com.google.Chrome" =         {
            LastActiveDate = "2015-10-11 00:45:56 +0000";
            LastActivePingDate = "2015-10-11 07:00:00 +0000";
            LastRollCallPingDate = "2015-10-23 06:59:59 +0000";
        };
        "com.goo
```

Is there a way to know from what file the information is read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that all the preferences are recorded in `~/Library/Preferences/` directory, and `com.google.Keystone.Agent` matches the plist file in the directory.